# Inaccurate distance travelled values

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

New to using the corelocation framework could use some help understanding why my code isnt working how I'd like it too. I want it to track the distance travelled but when the view fires up it does different things everytime. Sometimes itll jump to 1000 or another large value or itll increase by random increments. Can anyone see why this code isnt working for me?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 100; //update every 100 meters
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    startLocation = nil;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    if (startLocation == nil)
    {
        totalDistanceBetween = 0;
        self.startLocation = newLocation;
    }
    CLLocationDistance distanceBetween = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:startLocation ];
    startLocation = newLocation;
    totalDistanceBetween += distanceBetween;
    totalDistanceBetween = totalDistanceBetween * 0.001; //convert to m value to km
    NSString *tripString = [[NSString alloc]
                            initWithFormat:@"%.02f",
                            totalDistanceBetween];
    distance.text = tripString;
}
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated but: First the code adds distanceBetween (which is in meters) to totalDistanceBetween (which will be in km from previous call) and then it divides totalDistanceBetween by 1000 (but it's already in km from previous call).  Also, you probably should do self.startLocation = newLocation.

Comment: Thank you. I created a separate float value to hold the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out to me is that you set `startLocation` to `nil` **after** you tell the location manager to start giving you updates.

Depending on how `startLocation` is defined/initialized/reused, it might not contain the initial value you expect it to.